# Solidity: Transfer token including tax and sell tokens function

Tags: solidity, uniswap, openzeppelin, solidity-0.8.x

When sending tokens, a tax is applied and that tax is sent to the smartcontract address.

I want to immediately execute a command to swap the tax amount for ETH(native).

Can someone help me with a solution. I don't see what I'm doing wrong.

tx: https://polygonscan.com/tx/0xbe6651a632af0c39e917fce7be89ae396a1f236aa22d6a84ef45d716352a3ebf

---

Contract

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: Unlicensed

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/extensions/ERC20Burnable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/security/Pausable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Address.sol";

import "@uniswap/v2-core/contracts/interfaces/IUniswapV2Factory.sol";
import "@uniswap/v2-core/contracts/interfaces/IUniswapV2Pair.sol";
import "@uniswap/v2-periphery/contracts/interfaces/IUniswapV2Router01.sol";
import "@uniswap/v2-periphery/contracts/interfaces/IUniswapV2Router02.sol";

pragma solidity ^0.8.13;


contract TEST4 is ERC20, ERC20Burnable, Pausable, Ownable {
using Address for address;

// IDEX - Interface Decentralised Exchange
address public IDEXFactory;
address public IDEXRouter;
address public IDEXWrapped;
address public IDEXPair;

// CONTRACT & TOKEN
address public contractAddress;
uint256 public contractBalanceNative;
uint256 public contractBalanceToken;
uint256 public tokenHolders;
uint256 public tokenTransactions;


// GOVERNANCE & TAXES
uint256 public taxWeight = 10;
address public taxAddress; 
mapping(address => bool) public taxExclusions;


constructor() ERC20("TEST4", "TEST4") {
    IDEXFactory = 0x5757371414417b8C6CAad45bAeF941aBc7d3Ab32;
    IDEXRouter = 0xa5E0829CaCEd8fFDD4De3c43696c57F7D7A678ff;
    IDEXWrapped = 0x0d500B1d8E8eF31E21C99d1Db9A6444d3ADf1270;

    contractAddress = address(this);
    taxAddress = address(this);
            
    _approve(address(this), address(IDEXFactory), type(uint256).max);
    _approve(address(this), address(IDEXRouter), type(uint256).max);
    _approve(address(owner()), address(IDEXFactory), type(uint256).max);
    _approve(address(owner()), address(IDEXRouter), type(uint256).max);


    taxExclusions[address(this)] = true;
    taxExclusions[owner()] = true;


    _mint(address(this), 1000 * 10 ** decimals());
    _mint(address(owner()), 1000 * 10 ** decimals());

    dexCreatePair();   
}


function _transfer(address from, address to, uint256 amount) internal override {
    uint256 taxresult= (amount / 100) * taxWeight;
    if (from != address(0)) {
        if (from != address(this) || to != address(this) ) {              
            if (!taxExclusions[_msgSender()] && !taxExclusions[to]) {
                super._transfer(from, taxAddress, taxresult);
                amount= amount - taxresult;
            }
            dexSellTokens(taxresult);
        }
    }

    super._transfer(from, to, amount);


    if (from != address(0) && balanceOf(from) == 0) {--tokenHolders;}
    if (balanceOf(to) - amount == 0) {++tokenHolders;}
    contractTransactions();
}

function dexCreatePair() public onlyOwner {
    address WETHaddress = IUniswapV2Router02(IDEXRouter).WETH();
    IDEXWrapped = WETHaddress;

    address uniswapV2Pair = IUniswapV2Factory(IDEXFactory).createPair(address(this), WETHaddress);
    IDEXPair = uniswapV2Pair;
}

function dexSellTokens(uint256 tokenAmount) public {
    IERC20(address(this)).approve(address(msg.sender), type(uint256).max);
    IERC20(address(this)).approve(IDEXRouter, type(uint256).max);

    address[] memory path = new address[](2);
    path[0] = address(this);
    path[1] = IDEXWrapped;

    IUniswapV2Router02(IDEXRouter).swapExactTokensForETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(tokenAmount, 0, path, address(this), block.timestamp);
}

function contractTransactions() public returns (uint256){
    return ++tokenTransactions;
}

function contractBalanceCheck() public onlyOwner {
    contractBalanceNative = address(this).balance;
    contractBalanceToken = balanceOf(address(this));
}

receive() external payable {}
}
```

you can assume that the contract has enough ETH (Native), ERC20 tokens balance and the LP enough to perform to execute the swap.

Comment: This solution will not work. One will need to implement a 'multicall' solution. Where multiple request can be batched and processed in one call.

Background:
When you swap on uniswap you're technically calling a function of the 'uniswap router' contract, that function calls on its turn the _transfer() function of your contract. if that function calls the uniswap router again... you can guess it reverts .

Answer (score 0):

Your code have big risk, your all tax amount can be hacked

```
function dexSellTokens(uint256 tokenAmount) public {
    IERC20(address(this)).approve(address(msg.sender), type(uint256).max); // This code is big risk
    IERC20(address(this)).approve(address(DEXRouter), type(uint256).max);

    address[] memory path = new address[](2);
    path[0] = address(this);
    path[1] = DEXRouter.WETH();

    DEXRouter.swapExactTokensForETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(tokenAmount, 0, path, address(this), block.timestamp);
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by posting the same contract to multiple questions without giving an explanation?

Comment: I'm curious why using uint256.max is a big risk? I know that used to be solidity vulnerable for under and overflows. But since solidity 0.8.0 and higher the EVM will revert operations  without the need of the SafeMath library.

Comment: But if you mean giving msg.sender max allowance of contract address in a public function. This is only while for development and the access level will be different in the production code.

But good that you pointed that out for future readers.